# When I execute supervisorctl, It appears "error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: <string> line: 1"

Tags: supervisord

When I execute supervisorctl, It appears "error: , [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file:  line: 1"
Like this:

```
[root@10-10-216-144 downloads]# supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
[root@10-10-216-144 downloads]# supervisorctl reload
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: <string> line: 1
```

This is my configuration below:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf


[program:game_1]
directory = /data/code/game/handle
command = /data/code/gameenv/bin/python start.py
autostart = true
startsecs = 5
autorestart = true
startretries = 3
user = root    
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 20MB
stdout_logfile_backups = 20
stdout_logfile = /data/logs/xianxia/game_1_stdout.log
```

Have you ever met this problem before? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: gosh! It's very strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end. I removed the supervisor. And reinstalled it. It will generate a new supervisord.conf. And I rewrited '/var/tmp/supervisor.sock' to '/home/supervisor.sock'.
It work. Now I am very pleased.

Comment: How to remove the supervisor?